# Безопасно ли использовать один GPG ключ для разных сайтов?

Tags: шифрование, gpg

Если я привяжу к github тот же gpg-ключ, который я использую в bitbucket и почте, означает ли это, что владельцы github и bitbucket будут иметь доступ к обоим аккаунтам и смогут читать мою почту или же gpg-ключи устроены не так просто как пароли?

Comment: Один и нужно использовать. Публичный ключ предназначен для неограниченного распространения и не даёт никаких доступов, почитайте про основы асимметричного шифрования

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо. Скопируйте это в ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос.